# Reference Table OR Java Enum which is better

Tags: java, mysql, sql, enums, reference

I have a database entity: worker, and there are essentially two types of workers,

1. Full-Time
2. Part-Time

I am certain that this list of types won't grow frequently.

| id | name | worker_type_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam | 1 |
| 2 | Milne | 2 |

```
public class Worker{
 private int id;
 private int name;
 private WorkerType type;
}
```

For Worker_Type I have two options:

1. Create a Java ENUM of WorkerType

   ```
   public enum WorkerType{

    WorkerType(int id, String name){
     this.id = id;
     this.name = name;
    }

    int id;
    String name;
   }
   ```
2. Create a reference table that stores WorkerType.

| worker_type_id | worker_type_label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Full Time |
| 2 | Part Time |

I am inclined towards using "1" but I see a lot of people speak in favour of "2". Apart from the obvious comparisons, how in code would I query all Full-Time workers in the worker table?

select * from worker join worker_type
on worker.worker_type_id = worker_type.id
where worker_type = 'Full Time';

My question about the above query is how would my code know about the string "Full Time"? If someone mistakenly changed the label it would break the code completely. How do I handle this?

Comment: You can make the worker_type_label column ENUM data type that accept only two values Full Time and Part Time. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html.

Comment: I think  method 2 is the optimal. It easy to change and manage

Answer (score 1):

Your example code:

```
public enum WorkerType{

 WorkerType(int id, String name){
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
 }

 int id;
 String name;
}
```

… confuses your question. You are mixing your worker type with your actual workers.

Likely the code appropriate to your situation is a class to represent each worker.

```java
public record Worker( int id , String name , Classifation classifation ) {}
```

The type of worker is a separate enum, with only two named objects (one for full-time, one for part-time), and no need for a custom constructor.

```java
public enum Classifation { FULL_TIME, PART_TIME }
```

I would nest the type-of-worker enum within the worker class. That nesting makes clear that the type-of-worker enum objects are mainly used only within that class.

```java
public record Worker( int id , String name , Classifation classifation )
{
    public enum Classifation { FULL_TIME, PART_TIME }
}
```

Usage:

```java
Worker adam = new Worker( 1 , "Adam" , Worker.Classifation.FULL_TIME );
Worker milne = new Worker( 2 , "Milne" , Worker.Classifation.PART_TIME );

System.out.println( List.of( adam , milne ) );
```

When run.

> [Worker[id=1, name=Adam, classifation=FULL_TIME], Worker[id=2, name=Milne, classifation=PART_TIME]]

---

Your title asks:

> Reference Table OR Java Enum which is better

There are at least two factors to consider:

- Will the infrequent changes happen only while you are programming your Java app?
- Will other apps or the DBA need to do lookups on this data?

An enum in Java is for automatically instantiating a limited set of named objects known at compile-time. You cannot change the enum at runtime.

If there is any possibility of this information changing while your app is deployed, then an enum is not appropriate. Instead, you need to dynamically create a collection of objects during runtime.

If there is any possibility of other apps, or the [DBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_administrator), needing to look up this information, then you should record that info within the database rather than within your Java app.

Given your example scenario, I suspect you may want *both* enums in Java *and* look-up reference table in database.

---

Another approach is to use human-readable text instead of a plain integer as a `WORKER_TYPE` column. In your case, store textual values such as `Full-time` & `Part-time`, or `Full` & `Part`.  In this case, no need for the loop-up reference table. This approach assumes (A) there is no business need for the type code (`1` or `2`), and (B) there are no further columns to track in describing a type of worker.

Furthermore, in more sophisticated databases, you can have the database enforce the limited set of possible values being stored in that column.